# Accepting Nominations — Who should Moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally, Moderators♦ are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing three provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **Nominees!** Please indicate your acceptance by editing the answer to accept/decline the nomination. And please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="https://stellar.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://stellar.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="https://stellar.meta.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://stellar.meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Comment: Seems like there are only 2 nominations yet and all downvoted..What if all the nominations have negative scores?

Comment: @AJ This is not an election. Nominees are a starting point to show interest in who might make good pro tems for this site.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

Hi!

I'm nominating myself.

I'm Ali, I'm the developer evangelist at Stellar.org and I was the one who created the area51 proposal! I'm here to answer questions on behalf of the Stellar team - it's now part of my (and @Rob's) job. I look forward to generating a conversation and providing answers to help people develop using Stellar. Thank you so much for creating this platform for us and our community!

(I accept this nomination)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

[image]

**I self-nominate.**

#### Notes:

I would be a good choice because I check the site often, am open about my mistakes, and look for ways to improve. I am not self-nominating myself out of pride, but to help the Stellar community as a whole. I am open to criticism because it helps me grow (see: the meta site and my declined/downvoted answers) haven't really been active in asking/answering questions, and it is because I am not the most informed person on this site. I do hang out in the review queues very often, though. I am also one of the community members that helped out with [lumenaut inflation pool](http://lumenaut.net).

Edit: I also try to frequently edit poorly formatted posts or posts with low readability.

**I accept this nomination.**

I live in NYC, so my active hours are from 10pm to 4am UTC, usually

Answer (score 5):

[image]

[image]
[image]

#### Notes:

I self-nominate.

I am committed to furthering the knowledge of the Stellar community through the StackExchange platform. I see the role of moderator as one of a light-handed curator; someone who keeps the organic growth of the community healthy - intervening when necessary to keep the site on-topic. Any moderator actions would be accompanied by explicit communication, because community members deserve to know why exceptional actions are taken.

I'm a long term StackExchange user, with 18k reputation on StackOverflow and membership of dozens of other communities. I have addressed many flagged issues on StackOverflow over the years.

I am currently building (yet another) language SDK for the Stellar API, so am actively learning the minutiae of those endpoints.

**I accept this nomination.**

I live in Australia. From time to time there are koalas in my yard. I am generally active on this site from 11pm to 7am UTC.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because I see them answering and overall being an active member of the community often. They seem to be very knowledgeable and their answers are always clean (concise & well formatted). They also respond to feedback and accept it, which are good qualities that are necessary for a good moderator. Example [(look at the comments)](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/193/can-an-inflation-pool-be-hacked-to-send-all-weekly-lumens-to-1-address-third-p/194#194)

And yes, I do not know who this person is at all.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]
[image: profile for Chenmunka on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

I would like to put myself forward as a moderator of this site.
I am already a pro-tem moderator at [Retrocomputing.SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) and so I am familiar with the [Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) applied to these sites.

Why has it taken me so long after this call was posted to volunteer?
Because I am here to learn rather than to teach.  I am not (yet) an expert in Stellar so I have been reticent in coming forward.  There are more knowledgeable people out there than me.  However, I am gaining more knowledge by the day.  By increasing my involvement here and bringing my experience of the SE network, I hope to both improve myself and help this valuable site through to eventual graduation.