# Moderator Election - Would you stand?

Tags: discussion, graduation, election

As you know, about this time last year the Stellar site [Graduated](https://stellar.meta.stackexchange.com/q/173/683) from Beta status.

It's time to hold an election for moderators of the graduated site.
This will be our first election, as up to now we have had [nominated](https://stellar.meta.stackexchange.com/q/37/683) [pro-tem](https://stellar.meta.stackexchange.com/q/51/683) moderators.

We need to hold a new election to install an active moderation team. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's formal nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position.

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a pulse check to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up. Posting an answer to this question does not commit you to standing in the election when it runs.